# Assembly won't print digits

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn assembly.  I wanted to write a simple program that counted to 20 and printed out the numbers.  I know you have to subtract ascii '0' from a ascii representation of a number to turn it into it's digit, but my implementation just refuses to work.  I still get 123456789:;<=>?@ABCD

Here is my code.

```
section  .bss
    num resb 1


section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, '1'
    mov ebx, 1          ; Filehandler 1 = stdout
    mov ecx, 20         ; The number we're counting to
    mov edx, 1          ; Size of a number in bytes

l1:
    mov [num], eax      ; Put eax into the value of num 

    mov eax, 4          ; Put 4 into eax (write)

    push ecx            ; Save ecx on the stack
    mov ecx, num        ; print num
    int 0x80            ; Do the print
    pop ecx             ; Bring ecx back from the stack

    mov eax, [num]      ; Put the value of num into eax

    sub eax, '0'        ; Convert to digit
    inc eax             ; Increment eax
    add eax, '0'        ; Convert back to ascii

    loop l1

    mov eax,1           ; System call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80            ; Call kernel
```

Can anyone see what the problem is? I'm totally hitting a brick wall. I'm using nasm to compile and ld to link.

Comment: The formula you mention (subtract '0', isn't adding '0'?) works for numbers with one digit. For more than one digit you will have to create a proc to convert the number to string in order to display it.

Comment: Does anyone have a good FAQ duplicate target for questions about multi-digit numbers?  I couldn't find one when adding the FAQ section to [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Your loop only prints a single byte each time.  You know that `10` is two bytes, right?  How could your idea possibly work?  Think about what the ASCII representation of `10` is.

Comment: okay, thanks for the tips.  That's pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @PeterCordes `'10'` is two bytes... `10` can be only 4 bits if desired. ;) (nitpicking, sorry :) ) (but it actually illustrates nicely the thing the OP missed, and has to understand)

Comment: @Ped7g: ok fine, `"10"` (the string) is two bytes, not counting a terminating zero, which you don't need when calling sys_write.